# calling conda source activate from bash script

Tags: macos, shell, virtualenv, conda

I'm trying to activate my conda env via a bash script. Even though the script runs fine and my PATH appears to be changed within the script, it's getting reset somehow after the script terminates. I can call `source activate test` from the cmd line and it works fine. An example along with output below.

**script:**

```
PycharmProjects/test » cat ./example.sh
echo "before calling source: $PATH"
source activate test
echo "after calling source: $PATH"
```

**output:**

```
./example.sh
before calling source: /Use rs/me/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

discarding /Users/me/miniconda3/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/me/miniconda3/envs/test/bin to PATH

after calling source: /Users/me/miniconda3/envs/test/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`
```

but if I `echo $PATH` after the script finishes, you can see that the `$PATH` has not changed (i.e. no `/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/test/bin`):

`PycharmProjects/test » echo $PATH /Users/me/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

Comment: `echo $PATH` **where** says that? Are you running `example.sh` as a script itself (i.e. `./example.sh`)? Instead of `source`ing it (i.e. `source example.sh`)?

Comment: running `example.sh` as as script (./example.sh). I called `echo $PATH` after script finished running, just to show $PATH is not actually changed.

Comment: Running it as a script the changes stop with the shell running the script. That's why you need to `source` the activate script to make it apply to the running script/shell in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to source virtualenv activate in a Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Thanks sourcing the script fixes it.

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up forcing my script to be sourced. That caused other troubles (such as running it with set -e) - eventually it was worth changing to to "ordinary" run (not sourced) and apply the accepted answer. Thanks for asking this!

Comment: _after the script finishes_  : Well, you seem to run the script as a child process. You can't then expect the PATH in the parent process to magically be changed as well, can you? Of course this is nothing specific to the variable PATH, but to any environment variable.

Answer (score 188):

On more recent versions of conda (4.6+), I have noticed that the following works:

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate <env-name>
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit why do we need `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"`?

Comment: `conda shell.bash hook` returns a string of bash.  I suppose you could right this out to a file and then source that file, but it is easier/faster to eval it.

Comment: @AnthonyScopatz That explains what you're doing, but not why. `conda activate <env>` works just fine without that eval expression, so it's still not clear why you're doing that.

Comment: When `conda activate` errors out requesting `conda init` to be run, the eval expression here makes it work without `conda init`.

Comment: Getting: `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`

Comment: I'm getting: `Could not find conda environment: <env>`

Comment: Works for me! would be great for anaconda to put this in the CLI

Comment: This perfectly worked for me.... without the eval statement I was getting: CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. But the eval statement solved it..so thank you!

Comment: I am still not sure why this works (but it does). I can run `source activate $CONDA_ENV` without any error, but the environment is not actually loaded until I add the eval command OP suggests.

Comment: If you do `echo "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` you can see that it is the script that is normally run when bash starts to setup the conda environment.  I don't understand why it's needed in the script though.

Answer (score 44):

I have found the following to work on Mac OSX running a bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /Users/yourname/anaconda/bin/activate your_env
python --version # example way to see that your virtual env loaded as expected
```

Make sure you make the scripted executable with:

```
chmod +x yourscript.bash
```

Comment: It worked for me on ubuntu 18, conda 4.9. It took less time than the  Anthony Scopatz approach. The reason is out of my understandings.

Answer (score 34):

### Interactive Shell

The `conda activate` command is intended for *interactive* shell sessions. One solution is to deliberately run the script in an interactive shell. This can be done through a shebang (if planning to use `./example.sh` call):

**example.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
echo "before calling source: $PATH"
## `source activate` is deprecated
conda activate test
echo "after calling source: $PATH"
```

or, by specifying via flags to the shell:

```bash
## bash
bash -l example.sh

## zsh
zsh -i example.sh
```

All of these assume that the executing user has run `conda init` for the shell.

### Using `conda run`

For *programmatic* execution within an environment, Conda provides the `conda run` command. Rather than muck around with shell state, let Conda guarantee execution within the environment:

**crun_example.sh**

```bash
echo "PATH outside environment: $PATH"

## printing shell variables is complicated by escaping
conda run -n test bash -c "echo \"PATH inside environment: \${PATH}\""

## but realistic application is usually a non-trivial script
conda run -n test python my_script.py
```

Code that involves user-facing I/O will often need a `--live-stream` flag. See `conda run --help` for details.

Answer (score 6):

See the link below,

[digitalocean-how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)

below is the snippet from the website,

> This is because environmental variables are only passed to child
>   processes. There isn't a built-in way of setting environmental
>   variables of the parent shell. This is good in most cases and prevents
>   programs from affecting the operating environment from which they were
>   called.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a workstation with the spec:

- Fedora `37`
- Bash:  `GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
- conda: `23.7.2`

None of these solutions worked for me, neither using bash interactive mode, nor login mode,  nor `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"`, etc.

I have a workaround for this issue for everyone like me being unable to make those solutions worked:

1. Create a bash file named `activate.sh` in the project folder with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
conda activate your_env_name
```

2. Add an alias in `~/.bash_aliases` like this:

```
alias conda-activate='test -f $PWD/activate.sh && source $PWD/activate.sh'
```

3. Run `conda-activate` in your project folder

I know the question is about macos, but this is the most referenced issue for this problem in stackoverflow and I think is a good place to post my solution here.