# Programatically execute a program inside a conda virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I use pyrobuf (a protobuf package) in Python 3. In order to use a proto-pattern you run `pyrobuf <filename> --install` which will compile the pattern and copy it to the `site-packages` folder from where you can import it.

I'm trying to do this via a script (which is quite straight forward). However I ran into a problem when trying to run pyrobuf inside a virtual environment.

I have somethin like this:

```
cmd = ['activate', <envname>, '&&', 'pyrobuf', <filename>, '--install', '&&', 'deactivate']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When run this installs the proto-pattern to my main anaconda install not to the (supposedly active) environment.

I'm installing pyrobuf to each individual environment but that doens't seem to make a difference.

Any help on how to run a programm 'inside a conda environment' is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am able to run scripts inside of an unactivated conda env by running: "/path/to/anaconda/envs/env_name/bin/python filename.py". Are you trying to activate the environment programmatically as well?

Comment: Following stackoverflow answer might work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395091/1155185