# 'Conda activate base' fails to load when executed from Matlab on Ubuntu (18.04). Error: conda: command not found

Tags: bash, matlab, ubuntu, conda, environment

My Conda working perfectly from the ubuntu terminal. I can easily activate the environment I need using the following command

`$ conda activate base`

and it loads the base environment on the terminal.

**But here, in MATLAB, when I try to activate conda environment using the following command it returns an error**

```
>> system('conda activate base')
/bin/bash: conda: command not found
```

Based on [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395958/calling-an-anaconda-environment-from-matlab-conda-command-not-found) with similar discussions, I have tried the following but to no luck

```
>> system('/home/anirudha/anaconda3/bin/conda activate base')

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.

>> system('conda init bash');
/bin/bash: conda: command not found
```

I have also tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found) but to no success again.

My purpose is to execute a few gdal functions from the command line through a MATLAB script. I have tried doing this on my windows PC, and everything works perfectly. But not on my Linux station. Am I missing something?

Comment: You last command is wrong, it shoudl be `system('/home/anirudha/anaconda3/bin/conda init bash')`, however note that I do not think that MATLAB command line is `bash`.

Comment: Thanks, Ander. This is the response that I get with the complete path `...
no change     /home/anirudha/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/anirudha/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/anirudha/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/anirudha/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/anirudha/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /home/anirudha/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/anirudha/.bashrc
No action taken. `. I'm not sure about the Matlab shell either.