# How to run a bash script from a python file?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, ubuntu, virtualenv

I want to run the following bash script from inside a python script.

```
condo activate bne
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python bne.py --model models/BNE_SGsc --fe ./embeddings/BioEmb/Emb_SGsc.txt --fi names.txt --fo output_BNE_SGsc.txt
```

My python script/function to do this is as follows -

```
def do_tensorflow_routine(path_name_file):
    os.chdir(os.path.join("../","bne_resources/"))
    os.system("conda activate bne")
    bne_command = "python bne.py --model models/BNE_SGsc --fe ./embeddings/BioEmb/Emb_SGsc.txt --fi names.txt --fo names_bne_SGsc.txt"
    subprocess.run(bne_command,shell=True)
    pass
```

However, I am getting the following error -

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I am using a cluster and my system specifications are as follows -

```
   Static hostname: lab1
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
        Machine ID: 104265a0ea5b48c1a3c5a9802294af66
           Boot ID: 4277780744ae448292d66a9ff39c76e2
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-36-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Please let me know if I am missing something. My basic question is how to run another python script from a given python script, especially when we need to activate and deactivate virtual environments, since the parent python script and child python script require 2 different virtual environments due to some dependency conflicts.
Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance,
Megh

Comment: `os.system("conda activate bne")` only works within the shell that `os.system()` starts, which exits as soon as that `os.system()` finishes running. That doesn't mean that `conda activate` doesn't run, but it _does_ mean that each `os.system()` call is independent -- you can't expect one such call to change the state of the shell started by future ones.

Comment: You need _both_ the `conda activate` _and_ the code that depends on it to be run from the _same_ `subprocess.Popen` instance.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy - thanks for your reply. I saw the related post that you mentioned which is similar to this, and I tried modifying the statement to the following - ` subprocess.run(f"""conda init bash conda activate bne python bne.py --model models/BNE_SGsc --fe ./embeddings/BioEmb/Emb_SGsc.txt --fi names.txt --fo names_bne_SGsc.txt
    conda deactivate bne""",shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', check=True)`
But, I keep getting the same `CommandNotFoundError` as mentioned in the original post. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thank you again!

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the attempt (as informed by the existing question's answers) and the new error? I suspect some formatting got lost in putting it into a comment, and the details are critical.

Comment: Part of the likely problem is that `conda init` modifies dotfiles, but a noninteractive shell doesn't _read_ dotfiles and won't get any of the benefit of those modifications.

Comment: ...so, what you might need to do is `source` in whatever configuration conda relies on. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52813960/14122 for an example of that. (I've added the question that answer is attached to to the duplicate list).

Answer (score -1):

If the terminal does not show (base) after running conda activate bne, then try running:

`conda init`

In the bash script at the top you need the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and env is used for portability for different distributions of Linux.

Comment: The OP isn't running `conda activate` in a terminal at all; they're running it in a noninteractive shell started by their Python process. Advice to look at what the terminal prompt shows is completely moot / irrelevant. Beyond that, this question has already been asked and answered elsewhere on the site already; in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have already been asked and answered many times before".