# How to activate anaconda environment in bash script

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda

I want to write a simple bash script that activates an anaconda environment and opens jupyter notebooks in that environment.  I just want to simplify starting notebooks with a preferred environment.

This is what I have:

```
cd ~/my_notebooks_folder
conda activate my_env
jupyter-notebook
conda info
```

However, this still results in the `base` environment to be active and the notebooks are running using the `base` python.

I found two questions about this issue on StackOverflow. However, neither helped me. It seems that the functionality of `conda` been changed since those questions were posted?

I'm on Ubuntu and Linux Mint. conda version : 4.5.12.

These are the other questions/answers I tried:

- [calling conda source activate from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534513/calling-conda-source-activate-from-bash-script)
- [How to source virtualenv activate in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Have you installed the Jupyter Notebook in `my_env`?

Comment: Yep. That did the trick. I could kick myself.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by darthbith solved my problem; I need to install the Jupyter Notebook into `my_env`.