# Bash script with multiple commands stops when entering new conda environment

Tags: linux, bash, conda

I want a command that I can add to my `~/.bashrc` which does the following in this order:

- cd to a directory
- activate a conda environment
- open a jupyter notebook.

The command that I have currently looks like this:

```
alias foo='
cd ~/Documents/bar
conda activate foobar
jupyter notebook
'
```

But execution stops after the `conda activate foobar` command.

Is there a way that I can ensure that all 3 commands are performed, and that it does not stop when I go into a new environment?

Comment: Use a function, not an alias, for compound commands. Beyond that, check that `conda activate` modifies the state of the shell you already were running; if it starts a new shell instead, *of course* that new shell won't continue executing the same function or alias.

Comment: One way you can test that is to look at whether running `conda activate` changes `$BASHPID`. Alternately, you can look at `type conda`. If `conda` itself is a function, it could be capable of modifying the state of your running shell. If it's an external script (and is executed as such rather than sourced), starting a new shell is the only way it could possibly be implemented.

Comment: Alternately, you might consider the approach taken by the already-answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534513/calling-conda-source-activate-from-bash-script

Comment: Or add `;` between commands, carriage returns will not work in an alias.