# How to execute a script in a virtual environment from a bash script on server?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, virtualenv

I am trying to run a python script in a virtual environment in a server using oarsub :

So firstly I run this command in a server name "a" :

```
oarsub -l /host=1/gpu=1,walltime=2:00:00 './training_corpus1.sh'
```

training_corpus1.sh looks like this at the beguinning :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ge/ke/anaconda3/envs

source activate env

cd ~/eXP/bert

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python training.py \
    --exp_name bert \ ...
```

At the beguinning,  I am suppose to open my virtual environment and then run the script but I am always getting this error in the OAR.18651.stderr file :

```
./training_corpus1.sh: line 5: activate: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 18, in <module>
    from xlm.slurm import init_signal_handler, init_distributed_mode
  File "/home/ge/ke/eXP/bert/xlm/slurm.py", line 11, in <module>
    import torch
ImportError: No module named torch
```

Torch is located in my virtual environment , it seems that It did not open.Whenusing "conda " a thte place of "source" I get:

```
./training_corpus1.sh: line 5: conda: command not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calling conda source activate from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534513/calling-conda-source-activate-from-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

For a virtual environment and `bash` the activation command is

```
source env/bin/activate
```

where *env* is the directory of the virtual environment to activate.

PS. Let me advice you to start any script with `set -e` to allow fast failing on any error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
…
```

Comment: So I should write  source /home/ge/ke/anaconda3/envs/env/bin/activate ?

Comment: After `cd /home/ge/ke/anaconda3/envs` you can use relative path: `source env/bin/activate`. `env` is now a subdirectory of the current directory.

Comment: it gices this :  ./training_corpus1.sh: line 8: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory it seems activate does not exist in env/bin   like :  (env) ke@dere2:~/anaconda3/envs/env/bin$ cd activate
-bash: cd: activate: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: `activate` must be present in a virtual environment and must be a bash script. Not sure about `conda` though.