# mamba equivalent of `conda shell.bash hook`

Tags: shell, conda, mamba

I'd like to use
`mamba activate [env]` [in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56155771/16652739).

What would be the equivalent of `conda shell.bash hook`?
I've tried `mamba shell.bash hook` and `mamba shell hook -s posix`.

Comment: Why do you need this? Sounds XY-ish to me.

Comment: @merv to run `mamba activate`

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize mamba in your shell with the command `mamba init`.

However, you may want to run the hook subcommand in a non-interactive bash script where you need to activate an environment. There's no equivalent of `conda shell.bash hook` for mamba. To initialize mamba "on the fly", you must source the file `$MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh`, for example: `source ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh`.

You want to do this **after** initializing conda with `eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"`.

Comment: Works for me (zsh) if initializing conda with `. $(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`.

Comment: @function2 that's the same result as the hook, but you still need to source mamba.sh if you want to use `mamba activate`. I like the idea of the subshell to capture the conda prefix, but it requires `conda` to be in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the full path to your mamba installation, the following works:

```
source ~/.lib/mamba/bin/activate [env]
```

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put `mamba activate`(or `micromamba activate`) in your shell script without initializing the shell, you will get an error message that suggests you

```
'micromamba' is running as a subprocess and can't modify the parent shell.
Thus you must initialize your shell before using activate and deactivate.

To initialize the current  shell, run:
    $ eval "$(micromamba shell hook --shell )"
and then activate or deactivate with:
    $ micromamba activate
To automatically initialize all future () shells, run:
    $ micromamba shell init --shell  --root-prefix=~/micromamba
If your shell was already initialized, reinitialize your shell with:
    $ micromamba shell reinit --shell 
Otherwise, this may be an issue. In the meantime you can run commands. See:
    $ micromamba run --help
```

therefore just initialize the shell before the activation

```
#! /usr/bin/zsh
eval "$(micromamba shell hook --shell zsh)"
micromamba activate
python --version
```

then you should get the python version installed in your mamba environment properly.

**Make sure you change the shell name as I'm using `zsh`**