# Activate virtualenv INSIDE the my current bash (no subprocess)

Tags: bash, virtualenv

> I want to have a generic BASH script witch activates my virtual
>   environment inside a given folder.

- The script should be able to be called from from any folder I have a virtual environment in.
- If there is no virtual environment it should create one and install the pip requirements.

I can not run the activation inside my original BASH only as a subprocess (see `--rcfile`). Just `source`-ing it is not working!

Thats my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# BASH script to run virtual environment

# Show errors
set -x

DIR_CURRENT="$PWD"
DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV="$PWD/venv"
FILE_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python2.7"
FILE_REQUIREMENTS="requirements.txt"
FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH="$DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate"

# CD to current folder
cd ${DIR_CURRENT}

echo DIR: $(pwd)

# Create the virtual environment if not existing
if [ ! -d ${DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV} ]; then
    virtualenv -p ${FILE_PYTHON} ${DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV}
    chmod a+x ${FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH}
    source ${FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH}
    pip install -r ${FILE_REQUIREMENTS}
fi

/bin/bash --rcfile "$FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH"

# Disable errors
set +x
```

I use Mac OSX 10.10.5 and Python 2.7.

Sadly existing [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943208/activate-a-virtualenv-with-a-python-script), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script) questions couldn't answer my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what you are trying to do has already been nicely solved by a project called [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

---

About your question: Use a function instead of a script. Place this into your bashrc for example:

```
function enter_venv(){

    # BASH script to run virtual environment

    # Show errors
    set -x

    DIR_CURRENT="$PWD"
    DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV="$PWD/venv"
    FILE_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python2.7"
    FILE_REQUIREMENTS="requirements.txt"
    FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH="$DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate"

    # CD to current folder
    cd ${DIR_CURRENT}

    echo DIR: $(pwd)

    # Create the virtual environment if not existing
    if [ ! -d ${DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV} ]; then
        virtualenv -p ${FILE_PYTHON} ${DIR_VIRTUAL_ENV}
        chmod a+x ${FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH}
        source ${FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH}
        pip install -r ${FILE_REQUIREMENTS}
    fi

    /bin/bash --rcfile "$FILE_VIRTUAL_ACTIVATE_BASH"

    # Disable errors
    set +x
}
```

The you can call it like this:

```
enter_venv
```

Comment: Thank you, as I understood it `virtualenvwrapper` is just creating environments globally? Is it also automatically building and activating them? The function you posted is sadly not running inside my "root" shell, still creating a new one.

Comment: virtualenvwrapper can do what you want. Just read the docs (completely). To make my above example work you need to start a new terminal/shell. Otherwise your bashrc doesn't get's sourced again. (Please don't tell me you put the function in a script and executed it!)

Comment: Is it possible for you to also post a virtualwrapper example?

Comment: with virtualenvwrapper: `mkvirtualenv -ppython2.7 NAME`.. And from then `workon NAME`.. You need to manually execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Make sure that you installed virtualenvwrapper properly as described in the manual

Comment: Thanks you. Is there something witch types workon automatically when I enter an "existing" workfolder?

Comment: At the end you don't want that.