# pip installs packages in virtualenv and globally when called from bash script

Tags: python, bash, pip

I am trying to activate a python environment and installing some packages using pip in a bash file. It succeeds to install in the environment but also installs globally on my mac, and I don't understand why.

script.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source '<absolute path>/venv/bin/activate'
which pip
pip install psutil
pip list
```

output:

```
$ ./script.sh
<absolute path>/venv/bin/pip
...
Package          Version  
---------------- ---------
pip              19.0.3   
psutil           5.6.3    
setuptools       41.0.1  
wheel            0.33.1
```

But, in another terminal without the virtual environment it also gets installed:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip
$ pip list
Package          Version  
---------------- ---------
pip              19.0.3   
psutil           5.6.3   
setuptools       41.0.1    
wheel            0.33.1
```

If i type the commands in the script one by one in the terminal, it works as expected.
What am i missing?

edit:
If i run `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` (either in env or globally) it removes the packages both in the virtualenv and globally.
If i run the script again and I list the content in 'site-packages' `ls venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages` the installed package is not there, so my 'venv/bin/pip' is somehow pointing to my global 'site-packages'?

edit2:
I found a way to reproduce the behaviors.
1. create an environment `python -m venv venv_test`
2. activate the environment `. venv_test/bin/activate`
3. edit `source '<absolute path>/venv_test/bin/activate'` in script.sh
4. run script `./script.sh`

Why does this make pip install globally?

If i skip 2. it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running this in a bash script runs the commands in a different shell, then returns you to your original shell.  Running `source <path>/bin/activate` runs this in you current shell, hence this works from the command line. Your bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "<absolute path>/venv/bin/activate"
which pip
pip install psutil
pip listenter code here
```

If you call this with `source script.sh` this will run this in you current shell and should work as expected.  Hope this helps.  There is some other methods here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13122219/7473057

An example method for virtualenvs:

1. create an environment `python -m venv venv_test` or `virtualenv venv_test`
2. activate the environment: `source ./venv_test/bin/activate` (on cmd line)
3. run script `./script.sh`, which has `source "<absolute path>/venv/bin/activate"` removed.

Alternatively, I think what you are after is a subshell, running everything inside, which is in the link above.

Comment: It should still install the packages in the virtual environment without `source`? I do not need the the environment after i have executed the script.

Comment: Maybe something like this then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50829922/7473057 You could execute the `source "<absolute path>/venv/bin/activate"` in a subshell?

Comment: I updated the question with an edit2. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You are activating it twice, not sure why you need to.  This is a working method: 
1. create an environment python -m venv venv_test
2. activate the environment: source ./venv_test/bin/activate (on cmd line)
3. run script ./script.sh, which has `source "<absolute path>/venv/bin/activate"` removed.

Comment: Testing this on my system, my system python `/usr/bin/python` cannot see any packages I install in that environment

Comment: Yes, i did not mean initially to do that, but when I do the pip installs globally. Your answer is good, but it does not help me. I want the the activation of the environment to happen in the "script.sh" shell, not my own.

Comment: Can you add your comment about the steps to your answer?