# Can't activate virtual environment - created with built-in python module venv while having Conda installed on my computer

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-venv

I created a python virtual environment using this command:

```
$ python -m venv panda
```

It has been created successfully but when I try to activate the environment using:

```
$ activate panda/Scripts/activate.bat
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Not a conda environment: F:\panda\Scripts\activate.bat
```

I'm using:

- conda 4.10.3
- Python 3.9.7
- Git Bash 2.35.1.windows.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this question: [How to source virtualenv activate in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script). It may help with activating environments in bash.

`. ./panda/scripts/activate` should activate your environment; however, it with be a Python virtual environment and not a Conda environment.

If you are trying to use a Conda virtual environment, this page may help: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html