# How to enter a virtual environment through a shell script?

Tags: sh, python-venv

I have written a short script to speed up creating, entering, and installing requirements into a virtual environment. The code is below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
red=$(printf '\033[31m')
reset=$(printf '\033[0m')
rm -rf .venv
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
echo '*' > .venv/.gitignore
if [ -f "requirements.txt" ]
then
        pip install -r requirements.txt
fi
echo $red"Virtual Environment Created"$reset
```

The part giving me problems is the `source .venv/bin/activate` line, as it doesn't actually run the activate file in the venv - all the requirements get installed to my local machine directly.

How can I make it switch to the venv?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. Instead of calling `venv` to run the script (as I placed it in `/bin`), I could just run `. venv` to run it properly. It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35156699/21107707).

Additionally, by setting an alias `venv='. venv`, I could simply call `venv` and have it work.